# Specifying schema for temporary tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm used to seeing temporary tables created with just the hash/number symbol, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    [Id] INT
)
```

However, I've recently come across stored procedure code that specifies the schema name when creating temporary tables, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Test]
(
    [Id] INT
)
```

Is there any reason why you would want to do this?  If you're only specifying the user's default schema, does it make any difference?  Does this refer to the `[dbo]` schema in the local database or the tempdb database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It won't make any difference if you *are* specifying the users default schema, but if the users default schema changes then it will try to keep the temporary table in the dbo schema.

Temp tables are created in tempdb so (even if you could, as noted by Jim in comments) it means you'd need to maintain the schema in tempdb, and offers no benefit.

Comment: If you create a schema on tempdb, and map a user to tempdb with that default schema, running `CREATE TABLE #test (v INT)` will create the table as "**dbo**.#test". Trying to create a temp table under a schema other than dbo will ignore the schema you speciy and create it in the dbo schema regardless. So `CREATE TABLE dummy.#test (v INT)` will also create "**dbo**.#test".